# I am trying to insert form data into database but its give error(undefine index: name and fname)

Tags: php

THis is my html code i have checked multiple time but again its not working.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        <input type="submit" name=""><br>

    </form>
```

This is my php code i think code is correct but don't know its not working.

```
<?php
//include("php\DB.php");

$connection=new mysqli("localhost","root","","sms");
if($connection){
    echo "Connected";
}else{echo "Sorry";}



$username=$_POST["name"];
$fname=$_POST["fname"];



 $query="INSERT INTO student(name,fname)VALUES('".$username."','".$fname."')";



$connection->query($query);


?>
```

Comment: post your php code as well

Comment: It seems that may be your table field is different. please post structure of student table.

Comment: use error_reporting(0); or declare the variables before using them.

Comment: or may be your form action is not correct. my be form didn't able to find `insert.php`

Comment: table fields are(id, name , fname ,gender etc.)

Comment: are both `form code` and php code files are at same location?

Comment: @MuhammadYounas. May be there is space in field name of table. Could you please check?

Comment: @RoshanDandgavhal  that will not produce undefined index error. it will just related to form and php code  before query

Comment: yes i have checked multiple time there is no space in field name and also action path is correct but i don't know why its giving the error when send data its shows that the data is gone to php but its not inserting in database

Comment: echo $query. Put this query in phpmyadmin and check.

Comment: Make sure You are getting POST data, Please check print_r($_POST) & see the result

Comment: i have did echo $query also in the same page its working and also in php my admin query is correct

Answer (score 0):

according to my little knowledge please give space between insert statement

```
insert into student(name,fname) values('$username','$fname');
```